# Making a fake tld complete with domain registration

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, html, domain, tld

I am going to make a private, separate wifi network as part of a demonstration. People are going to connect to this network and I would like them to be able to visit fake websites with fake TLDS on their own devices (such as "random.hello"). I also would like to be able to dynamically allocate new domains on this network that will point to different HTML pages on one web server.

Using dnsmasq and Apache Virtual Hosts appear to be the best way to go.

I'm lost on exactly how would I go about doing this.

Comment: Have you tried anything? The dnsmasq allows you to setup `address=/<name>.<tld>/<LAN-ip>` and then Apache just reacts to that domain name as you would normally do with a standard name. You should first try by hand and then implement the necessary to update the different configuration files to support the new domain name(s).

Comment: Whats your purpose? There are a number of waya of achieving thus depending on your goal.  The general idea though would be to run an authorative nameserver - possibly alongside or combined with a forwarding or recursive server, and to either intercept dns requests or hand out your own DNS infrastructure. Of-course you also need something to habdle web service etc.